Why do I get these ugly breaks in my model? In the tutorial I'm following the edges do look smooth

I'm experiencing these breaks in my model. I have a bevel modifier on it and when I turn the edges down the problem gets less noticeable but does not disappear.

Hello could you please only share the piece with the bad shading? https://blend-exchange.com/

I found a fix for it. I had to turn off "clamp overlay"

You mean Clamp Overlap? But if you disable it it will generate bad topology, the faces of your bevel will intersect
